# MVC Dropdownlist with Angular Selecting default

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am new to both MVC and AngularJS.
I am having a layout page and in layout page partial view which is having dropdown and render body.
On selection change of any value content will change of view in render body.
I am using MVC `@Html.DropDownList` Since my data List is in session.

Now I want to change view data on change of dropdown values I am doing it with Angular.

Below is my code of partial view.

```
@Html.DropDownList("LoanAccountTypeModels", new SelectList(((MyModel.UserDetailsModel)Session["UD"]).LoanAccountTypeModels), new { style = "height: 30px; width:250px;", ng_change = "UpdateChildViews()", ng_init="LoanAccountTypeModel = options[0]" , ng_model = "LoanAccountTypeModel" })
```

my _Layout page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Styles.Render("~/css/_Layout")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/jquery.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/_Layout.js")
</head>
<body ng-app="ClientPortalGlobalNGApp">
    <div id="wrapper" ng-controller="ClientPortalGlobalNGController">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <div> <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="../assets/img/axis_bank_logo.png" style="width:65%;"> </a></div>
            </div>
            @Html.Partial("_HeaderPartial")
        </nav>
    <h3>{{HomePageModel.TotalSanctionedAmt}}</h3>
    @RenderBody();
    </div>
</body>
```

and my _layout.js page is

```
function ClientPortalGlobalNGController($scope, $http) {

    $scope.UpdateChildViews = function (ddlAccountType) {
        if ($scope.CurrentSelected == "Home") {
            $scope.HomePageModel = { TotalSanctionedAmt: "10", CustomerDetail: { PrimaryHolderName: "X" } };
        }
    }
}
var app = angular.module("ClientPortalGlobalNGApp", []);
app.controller("ClientPortalGlobalNGController", ClientPortalGlobalNGController);
```

I have tried `$scope.form = { type: $scope.typeOptions[0].value };` in controller then it is selecting default but it is giving `TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined` and then angular code is not working and rendering as `{{HomePageModel.TotalSanctionedAmt}}` in final HTML instead of blank value.

Please suggest. I have been wandering on Stack overflow for 2 days. but no help.
Also please suggest me the best way to do it.

Comment: will u please share the code of controller ?

Comment: That's my controller code in _Layout.js file @MahbuburRahman

Comment: I meant the MVC controller from where u getting Session["UD"]. For dropdown, angular has an awesome directive ng-options. Have u tried it ?

Comment: Controller Code is binding List of LoanDetail to session["UD"] Entity which is having key and value property. does ng-options have access to server session?

Comment: It is possible to access server data from ng-controller using ajax. If u can build the list of LoanDetail for ng-options in ng-controller then it will works. Like this:  `<select data-ng-options="o for o in LoanDetails" data-ng-model="LoanAccountTypeModel"></select>`

Comment: Thanks.. I have done in similar way. I have written an $http call in controller and bind data to $scope and used ng-options.